# could not update amount as i want to input

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

please help for me wrong code. I have created a ajax onClick function but credit amount do not update. What is the problem ?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function togglediv(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}

function creditInput(id, amount) {
   
     var url = "my_campaigns?cat=ptc_normal";
     var amount = $('input[name=amount"]').val();
 
     $.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          url:url,
          data:amount,
          cache:false,

          success:function(data){
              document.location = "?cat=ptc_normal&allocate="+id+"&allocation_amount="+amount;
          }
     });
}
        
</script>
```

```html
<div id="ad_id">
<input type="text" id="amount_credit" name="amount">
<a onclick="creditInput(<?php echo $ad['id']; ?>)" href="javascript:void(0);">Pay</a>
</div>

<button onclick="togglediv(ad_id)">Toggle div</button>
```

Comment: First, `creditInput(<?php echo $ad['id']; ?>)` You missed a quote. It should be `creditInput("<?php echo $ad['id']; ?>")`

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy what if it's a no ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed a quote in:

```
var amount = $('input[name="amount"]').val();
//-------------------------^----------------
```

Comment: All is ok and page reload to success page but amount filed is empty call the url are showing www.example.com/my_campaigns?cat=ptc_normal&allocate=5&allocation_amount=

Comment: Guess you have to upload working code which illustrates your current problem.
At this point I can not point to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use this :

```
var amount = $('input[name="amount"]').val();
```

And then use object like syntax when passing data to server side :

```
data : {
   amount : amount
},
```

Check this, it will help you.

Comment: Do not update url www.example.com/my_campaigns?cat=ptc_normal&allocate=5&alloc‌​ation_amount=